# google test and wrap file meson

Tags: googletest, meson-build

Hi in my project I need to use google test and I use the
gtest.wrap file in order to download the gtest with the patch for meson

```
[wrap-file]
directory = googletest
source_url = https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.11.0.tar.gz
source_filename = gtest-1.11.0.tar.gz
source_hash = b4870bf121ff7795ba20d20bcdd8627b8e088f2d1dab299a031c1034eddc93d5
patch_filename = gtest_1.11.0-2_patch.zip
patch_url = https://wrapdb.mesonbuild.com/v2/gtest_1.11.0-2/get_patch
patch_hash = 764530d812ac161c9eab02a8cfaec67c871fcfc5548e29fd3d488070913d4e94

[provide]
gtest = gtest_dep
gtest_main = gtest_main_dep
gmock = gmock_dep
gmock_main = gmock_main_dep
```

but when i insert in the meson.build the call to gtest wrap

```
  gtest_proj = subproject('gtest')
```

the getst is cloned correctly but in the meson configuration I got the following error

..../meson.build:64:2: ERROR: Subproject exists but has no meson.build file

that is referred to the line where i call the dependency to gtest

Answer (score 2):

The googletest is CMake based project and thus try to import it with [cmake module](https://mesonbuild.com/CMake-module.html):

```
cmake = import('cmake')
gtest_proj = cmake.subproject('gtest')
```

You can also check [this implementation](https://gerrit.openbmc.org/plugins/gitiles/openbmc/stdplus/+/458aeae0c60c5c3afbfd5c87bd8637372b26e93d/test/meson.build) on how to build with own flags and declare dependency.